# Apache environment variables list?

Tags: apache-2.2

Do the apache docs have a full list of these variables? Or is there some way that I can find out what they are in apache? The variables are things like `%{Referer}` and `%{User-agent}`.

Comment: Variables allowed in `RewriteCond` are not the same thing as environment variables.  Which one are you interested in?

Answer (score 8):

Dave from addedbytes wrote this great cheatsheet:
https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/

Answer (score 6):

Apache HTTP Server [v2.4 documentation provides expression parser variables here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars) that includes the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` and `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` aspects you were seeking.

Also, keep in mind, the docs mention this and other details:

> Note that the value of a variable may depend on the phase of the request processing in which it is evaluated.

A bit different but somewhat related is [v2.4 documentation on environment variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html) that affect the Apache HTTP Server.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of standard variables are listed here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Modules can define their own variables as well:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars