# Apache2.4 How To remove from Access Log 200 code

Tags: apache-2.4, logging

I'm logging in access.log combined.
Here is my apache2.conf part about Log

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
LogFormat "%!200h %!200l %!200u %!200t \"%!200r\" %!200>s %!200O \"%!200{Referer}i\" \"%!200{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

I added the !200 to prevent logging all 200 code but it's not working. It still log - - - - "-" - - "-" "-"

Any Idea how to stop apache from Logging OK 200 but log everything else.

I try googling a lot and the only thing I can found is on the official Apache Page.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/logs.html

Answer (score 1):

After a log of googling I found that you can add this at the end of the line when you declare your custom Log.

```
"expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} > 200"
```

It will log if the status is higher then 200

You can customize this for your need.

```
"expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} >= 400"
```

My final config is :

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} > 200"
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

The answer was found here : [Prevent logging of 400 errors in Apache httpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/997624/prevent-logging-of-400-errors-in-apache-httpd)