# What would be the easiest way to exclude 206 requests from apache xampp log ? Thanks

Tags: logging, xampp, exclude

What would be the easiest way to exclude 206 requests from apache xampp log ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [Prevent logging of 400 errors in Apache httpd](https://serverfault.com/questions/997624/prevent-logging-of-400-errors-in-apache-httpd) should help. Basically what you want to setup is conditional logging, and filter on the environment variable REQUEST_STATUS:

`CustomLog logs/access-errors.log common "expr=%{REQUEST_STATUS} != 206"` should do what you want. Adapt the log path and log format to your liking.